# Is there any way to make sure the DataGridView columns stay the same size on high-resolution displays?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that after it is deployed on some systems the columns get really small, especially on high resolution laptops.  Is there any way to make sure the columns stay the same size?

The DataGridView itself is the same size but the last 2 columns shrink, and are therefore not usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the last 2 column's property, they may be set as "fill" in autoresizemode (under layout). change it to "displayed cells" or "column header".

Comment: Ah thanks.  I actually had to use fill for the last one since it is an address and it now functions perfectly!